# Downvoting during review - hits my score?

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Why is it that down-votes that I cast during review are reflected in my score? Am I misunderstanding the process?

Comment: Downvoting an answer has always impacted your score. Why would downvoting an answer during review be any different?

Comment: Yikes. Tough crowd. I didn't know this was the process.

Comment: on the bright side: you'll get it back when the answer is deleted. The probability that downvoted answers in the review will indeed be deleted is rather high. Be the first to downvote and watch the downvote stampede after you :-) Also, there's a high probability that someone flags it, with the same effect on deletion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you downvote any answer (except CW) then you will lose 1 reputation. Because there is no difference between voting directly and voting during the reviewing.

Comment: I don't get it! So I downvote someone, and it affects me when am not the person? Plus what is CW?